# How to check if IndexPath is valid?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsindexpath, indexpath

Prior to swift 3, i used to use for example:

```
let path = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
if (path != NSNotFound) {
//do something
 }
```

But now, since i use `IndexPath` class in swift3, i'm looking for the equivalent for the  `path != NSNotFound` check.

**Xcode8.3.1 compiler error:** *"Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'IndexPath' and 'Int'"*

Comment: Why would you check it like this? There's no way that code ever worked as-is since you can't compare `NSIndexPath` against `NSNotFound`.

Comment: The NSIndexPath initializer simply creates an object. In what way do you expect initializing an NSIndexPath where it is 'NotFound'? This is not a query. You might be mixing it with 'indexOf', which returns an optional that can be checked for nil.

Comment: @bauerMusic, that was just a bad  example. I was referring more to methods that return IndexPath. That would have been a better example ;) updated the question

Comment: Given your update, what's you definition of a valid index path? Is it simply whether the result is `nil` or not?

Comment: And you really should post code that actually worked for you under Swift 2 but is now giving you trouble under Swift 3.

Comment: I'm quite sure that `indexPathForSelectedRow` returned `nil` rather than `NSNotFound` even in Swift 2.

Answer (score 23):

To check if `IndexPath` exists, I use this extension function:

```
import UIKit

extension UITableView {

    func hasRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return indexPath.section < self.numberOfSections && indexPath.row < self.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section)
    }
}
```

And to use it I do something like this:

```
if tableView.hasRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I think this should be in a must-included extension.

Comment: I have an NSFetchedResultsController that's returning an index path with a row index of -1. So it might be worth checking for >= 0 as well.

Comment: This gives me `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffffffffff8) numberOfRows`. My indexpath is `[-1, -1]`

Comment: Nevermind got the issue. The logic check is incomplete.

Answer (score 11):

Semantically, to consider an indexPath *invalid*, you need something to check for such as a table view or a collection view.

Usually you can consider an **indexPath** invalid if it represents a row where there is no corresponding data in the data source. *(One exception would be "Load more" rows.)*

If you really need to create an invalid `IndexPath`, you can do:

```
let invalidIndexPath = IndexPath(row: NSNotFound, section: NSNotFound)
```

**After the update:**

`self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` returns an Optional so can be `nil` if there is no selected row.

```
if let path = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
  // There is a selected row, so path is not nil.
}
else {
  // No row is selected.
}
```

Anyway, comparing `path` against `NSNotFound` raises an exception in all cases.

Comment: Sorry, my example was not clear. updated the example. i was referring to methods that return an indexPath.

Comment: Thanks. that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Improving the answer by @pableiros to handle edge case where section or row less than 0. This will happen when the table is empty and you try to access it by `listOfSectionHeaders.count - 1`, `listOfRowsForSection.count - 1`

```
extension UITableView {
    func isValid(indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return indexPath.section >= 0 
            && indexPath.section < self.numberOfSections 
            && indexPath.row >= 0 
            && indexPath.row < self.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on a case where `collectionView(_:didEndDisplaying:forItemAt:)` returns an invalid indexPath, so I used `indexPath.isEmpty` to check whether indexPath was indeed a row/section indexPath.